# Removed answer that got downvoted should give downvoters a reputation point

Tags: feature-request, reputation, downvotes, voting, answers

In my opinion people should get rewarded by 1 reputation point if they downvoted a bad or wrong answer which then gets removed by the answer giver. (So they get their point back, and get 1 point as a reward, leaving them with a +1 overall.)

Currently, **Downvoting** only has **a downside**: you lose 1 reputation point, and have a chance to receive it back once the answer giver removes the bad answer.

**I think this should be implemented because:**

- This stimulates people to 'risk' the 'loss' of their single reputation point in order to point out that the answer isn't right;
- People will delete their wrong answer faster to get their lost reputation back (-2 per downvote)
- People will realise faster that they wrote a bad or wrong answer and will learn from their mistake.

Comment: @DaanHeskes, do you mean you could get a +1 overall (so gain rep) rather than just get the -1 back when deleted? At the moment if it's deleted you just get the -1 back so a net effect of zero.

Comment: To clarify - you are *not* suggesting that you should get one reputation point *on top* of the one you get back after the answer was removed? So downvoting + answer is removed nets you +1 rep?

Comment: @PeterJ I mean that you should get a +1 overall. Changed it in my question so it is more clear.

Comment: (Err, close vote retracted; the comment and edit you posted right after it shows that you actually are asking for a new feature after all.)

Comment: What this would accomplish is people downvoting posts needlesly in the hope of gaining that extra point. If more than 50% of answers you downvoted are deleted, you come out on top, right? Downvoting answers has a downside *on purpose*, why does it need an upside? Are bad answers not downvoted enough?

Comment: In my opinion they're not downvoted enough, or are not downvoted enough to make the answerer remove it, in my opinion this would reduce the amount of wrong content.

Comment: You know, instead of ***downvoting bad answers***, people could just ***upvote good ones*** `:P`

Comment: @DaanHeskes: we have a far bigger problem with bad quality questions. What kind of unhelpful answers do you have a problem with, that they are not being removed quickly enough?

Comment: @Cupcake: but people already upvote the bad answers. They need downvotes to signal to the reader they're bad and won't work.

Comment: @DaanHeskes: note also that if you have enough reputation on the site, you can just *vote to delete* downvoted answers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So basically you're saying that it doesn't matter whether or not people downvote since there are people with permissions to vote to delete these answers anyways?

Comment: @DaanHeskes: I am saying that there are already mechanisms in place to help remove obviously unhelpful answers or non-answers. I am still failing to see why there should be more incentive to downvote posts.

Comment: @DaanHeskes leave a comment about why an answer is wrong, then upvote all the good answers higher than it `:P`

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, if 50% of these answers you downvoted are deleted you come out on top, but I don't think that's worth the reward for the time spent.

Comment: @DaanHeskes: But why not just comment on the answer explaining why it is wrong and deserve downvoting? That has worked for me just fine so far. You still haven't given us examples or more tangible data to convince us we have a real problem with answers not getting downvoted enough.

Comment: @DaanHeskes: I see a real downside to your proposal and nothing to offset that downside. I see no need for the feature, because I don't believe there is a need for answers to be downvoted more. And if that was the case, why not a counter proposal removing the -1 cost for answers just like it is free to downvote questions? I wouldn't agree to that either, but at least it won't have the gaming angle to it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters removing the -1 cost basically makes it so that people are able to just downvote around without any risk. With the feature I suggest people do have a risk but also a reward, the risk isn't big; neither is the reward. I think it's not too much of a deal that people are getting 1 extra reputation point just because they let someone know their answer is bad. In my opinion this is completely fine and I think it should be this way. You get rewarded for your effort; that's how Stackoverflow works.

Comment: @DaanHeskes: The rewards are there to incentivise specific behaviour. It is the *behaviour* we want. The rep is the way to get there. You need to make a case we need the behaviour.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think that rewarding people to remove this content is only an upside to the community. People now learn when their answer is bad, and not only do they learn; also the downvoting people learn that they did something right, because they earned themselves a little reward.

Comment: @DaanHeskes: people *already* learn this. You seem to imply that they are not learning it enough, but I am not convinced of that. I asked you to give us data, stats, or at least good examples of answers that would have been downvoted more if your proposal is implemented. I am still missing that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I see this in almost every question with a few answers. For instance, I just opened a random question and seen this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23563868/2363481. I'm not sure if you have experience with jQuery but the solution/code he provides isn't right; he didn't do any research to make sure it was right. You can see there is another answer which is right, it has more upvotes than the wrong answer got downvoted. This is because people don't feel like risking 1 reputation point in order to make him delete the answer.

Comment: @DaanHeskes: The question is barely an hour old! The answer currently stands at -1, but doesn't have any comment on it explaining why it is wrong. **I see no problem here**, there is already a signal to future visitors the answer may not be helpful.

Comment: @DaanHeskes: I don't expect you to come up with that data right here, right now. But please *do* try to build a case for your feature request. That one link is entirely unconvincing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The answer has no comment on it explaining why it is wrong because this takes too much effort. That's why my feature would work so good; people don't have to waste time commenting to tell why someone wrote a bad answer because he was too lazy to do any research. Instead, they just downvote him and have the chance to get rewarded. Without a reward they won't downvote, you can tell that because the answer has less downvotes than the right answer has upvotes.

Comment: @DaanHeskes: We already have people asking for more feedback on their bad posts all the time. Your proposal certainly won't help for people receiving the downvotes. But your proposal doesn't have **anything** to do with people not willing to leave comments! That's entirely an orthogonal issue.

Comment: @DaanHeskes: People are not avoiding downvoting because they are avoiding commenting.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's not what I'm saying. I'm saying that people are avoiding downvotes because there is a risk, but no reward. And in fact it does have EVERYTHING to do with people not willing to leave comments. People don't leave comments because this is so common, people answer a lot without doing any research; I prooved it with a random post which is not even 1 hour old. In order to make it less common, you should reward people who downvote to compensate the risk.

Comment: @DaanHeskes: I find people don't leave comments because they fear retaliation, actually.

Comment: @DaanHeskes: The point you still haven't addressed is: Why do you feel people are not downvoting answers *enough*?

Comment: @MartijnPieters That surely is another reason why they don't comment, but I'm sure they also don't comment because bad answers are too common. This is also why I feel people are not downvoting enough: People writing bad answers don't learn from their bad answers because people don't downvote (no reward) nor comment (fearing retaliation or they just think it's a waste of time to comment because bad answers are too common). In order to solve these problems I came up with this suggestion so people now understand there is not only a downside to voting;

Comment: @MartijnPieters there will be less bad answer and don't have to fear retaliation, which results in an upward spiral.

Comment: @DaanHeskes: Last time: can you show us bad answers are not being downvoted *enough*, that they *systematically* instead gain upvotes? I want to see examples bad answers that *stayed on the site for a prolonged period of time*, and I want to see statistics. It is not enough to say you *feel people are not downvoting enough*.

Comment: @DaanHeskes: So far, this proposal is a solution looking for a problem. I don't see the problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters For me the reason that I experience this is already enough of a reason for this to be changed. I think it does more good than bad. I am one of these people who doesn't downvote because I feel it's not worth the risk. In fact I'd rather keep bad content on SO than to risk losing reputation I've earned by contributing; because there is no reward for pointing out someone said something bad. And I feel as if there are too many people who think the same.

Comment: @DaanHeskes: But you cannot from your own experience extrapolate how everyone is thinking. That's why I want you to give us stats and examples.  Without it, this is nothing but a "it'd be nice" proposal.  There *are* downsides to the proposal, and without real, tangible upsides, no further effort is going to be put into it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Fact is that I will not downvote nor react to wrong answers just because the reward doesn't compensate the risk. I don't mind whether it's going to be changed or not, I just came here to give out my suggestion as I think it's a serious case. If you don't think that way, feel free to, bye Martijn Pieters.

Comment: @DaanHeskes: You appear to feel slighted, I am sorry you feel that way. But proposals you make affect *everyone*, not just you. As such, you need to build a proper case for a change. I gave you my opinion on how your proposal stacks up, what is missing. If you put in the work and show there is a real need (beyond your own initial feeling about it) then your proposal stands a chance. And if we don't give you feedback on a proposal, how can you ever hope to build a solid proposal?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well I feel as if you don't understand the importance of what I am trying to clear up. That might be because you have permission to just vote to delete downvoted answers anyways. But I'd say end of discussion, I don't really mind whether or not this gets implemented and I'm not willing to waste more time as no-one seems to care about what is a problem in my eyes anyways.

Comment: @DaanHeskes: You could *make* us care by proving there is a problem to solve. That's the issue here; not may people believe that *answers* are being downvoted enough.

Comment: @MartijnPieters as I said I'm not willing to continue discussing about this. You are right as long as I don't proove my right, right?

Comment: @DaanHeskes: All I have done is laid out an argument, and gave you parameters by which I wish to be convinced. That's how a discussion normally goes! There is no need to resort to an ad hominem, is there? Sure, I, personally, am not convinced. That doesn't make me 'right' and you 'wrong'. So you rather have people agree with you at every turn, just because you say so, instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters In order to change something you must prove that the current thing is wrong, as long as you don't do that you aren't right. So I'm saying that I'm not right as long as I don't proove that I'm right. That's why I don't feel continuing dicussing, have a nice day.

Answer (score 7):

Welcome to the Internet. There be trolls here.

I've been trolled on SO over a matter of opinion. I've also been trolled for not telling the newbie who asked a simple question that his entire methodology of writing code is flawed (I do try to mention deprecated methods when applicable but you can get sucked down that rabbit hole really fast if you're not careful). There's no requirement that you leave a comment as to why you downvoted either. That's why you have shared pain with downvotes. -2 for the poster, -1 for the voter. It requires voters to put some "skin" in the game.

While I do appreciate that you want to encourage good answers on SO, I would say that the negative votes speak for themselves and if the author wants that blot removed that's their call. I've done it a few times where I misunderstood the question, answered incorrectly and deleted my response (you'll note there's a badge for having done this for a -3 or lower). But I've left downvoted answers up just because there was nothing wrong with them, people just disagreed with me.

Don't incentivize downvotes. Let the negatives speak.

Comment: You make a good point that there's a difference between an answer that is bad, doesn't go with your opinion (although SO tries to avoid pure opinion questions or argumentative ones), and an answer that is just plain factually wrong (even if answering the right question). On less visited questions, it's hard to tell downvoted wrong vs upvoted correct if, say, only a couple people have voted. Downvotes _should_ be encouraged for truly wrong answers. But, a comment that gets upvoted about why it's a wrong answer can easily be incentive enough.